# How to run integration / e2e tests for a Chrome extension in 2021?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome-extension, jestjs, puppeteer, cypress

I'm building a Chrome extension that removes some content from a website. I wanted to set up some integration and e2e tests on it in order to check...

1. functions that set values in the `chrome.storage` API
2. interactions with the extension's UI (i.e. when you click the extension icon next to the address bar)
3. whether the extension works well from an e2e standpoint

I'm a beginner in testing and I'm struggling to figure out what would be the best approach. Here's the options I've looked at so far:

- Cypress - can only do a part of 3; I say "a part" because the e2e would require me to look at changes in the `chrome.storage` API.
- Puppeteer & Jest - could work for Chrome, but features in Firefox are experimental and I'm planning to make the extension compatible with that browser.
- Selenium & Jest - seems like the only one that could work, but most of the answers I see here are from +3 years ago and it seems to require a lot to set up.

Is Selenium still the only option in 2021 for testing Chrome extensions?

Comment: *Puppeteer & Jest - could work for Chrome, but features in Firefox are experimental* - https://github.com/microsoft/playwright

Comment: @EstusFlask just checked out Playwright, only supports extension loading for Chrome/Chromium and they're not looking to expand it to Firefox: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/2644

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working on it for a week, I came to the conclusion that the best way to do this is with Selenium and Jest. The setup takes a bit to get used to it, but once you do it's pretty straightforward. My resources:

- https://github.com/applitools/jest-environment-selenium
- https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration

Answer (score 4):

Playwright supports testing of Chrome extensions out of the box and it's covering your 3 questions:

1. It lets you evaluate code in the background script during tests. After setting up playwright like described in [this article](https://blog.ai21.engineering/the-lonely-road-of-testing-chrome-extensions-end-to-end-d6a3654663ad), you can manipulate the chrome.storage like this :

```
test('setting storage key during a test', async ({ page, backgroundPage }) => {
  await backgroundPage.evaluate(() => {
    chrome.storage.sync.set('SomeKey', 'SomeValue');
  })
  ...
});
```

`backgroundPage` is coming from a fixture that should define like explained in the article (depending if you extension run in manifest v2 or v3).

2. You can navigate your extension pages under `chrome-extension://` like your popup.html, simply like this :

```
test('popup page', async ({ page, extensionId }) => {
  await page.goto(`chrome-extension://${extensionId}/popup.html`);
  await expect(page.locator('body')).toHaveText('my-extension popup');
});
```

3. Of course you can navigate to any web page and test your extension behavior on them.

Comment: here's the latest code: https://playwright.dev/docs/chrome-extensions